How to get Google Player User ID with lowest possible friction
In our game, we want to maintain a zero friction login mechanism which doesn't require any action from the user. To help them preserve game progress across devices, we would like to get the user's google play user ID, so we can tie their progress to that ID. Then if they play the game on another device logged in to this google play account, they can keep their progress.
Looks like this is the least friction non-deprecated way to retrieve the google play player ID. Is anyone aware of other methods?  Via this method, there will be a prompt to select the google play default account (no longer prompts after default account is selected), but otherwise no friction.
These two methods were also found but determined to be less appropriate.

https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg This is google sign in, not google play, and requires a full login which is not what we need as far as I can see.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount This one may actually have the least friction if the user is already logged in to google play services on the device, but I am not 100% clear on that from reading this doc.  This is also deprecated so likely shouldn't be used.

